# How to insert an Object (excel file) into PowerPoint using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, powerpoint

I need to insert an excel file into the PowerPoint slide using java Apache POI API. Can we do that with POI API?

Comment: For .ppt have a look at [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849102)

Comment: I am working with pptx files and i want to upload any files which are uploaded by users. Please share details if you know on this how to implement. Thank you.

Comment: I've created an preliminary [patch](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61797) - please give it a try.

Comment: Hi, Thank you @kiwiwings for the patch updates. I am working on this and update you once i am able to embed the excel in ppt. Could you please let me know will these changes be part of next release.

Comment: I've modified the patch already a lot and started to test other embeddings (Word, PDF). So the last preliminary patch won't be part of the release. Just subscribe to the ticket and you'll see my updates on it.

Comment: Sure @kiwiwings , I Subscribed. Thank you.