# XSLF :- embedding excel files in PPT

Tags: java, apache-poi, xslf

I might be asking a duplicate question here. I read multiple answers regarding OLE embedding but unable to find correct solution for my problem.

**My Problem**
I want to create a PPTX file and embed an excel to one of the slide. I found HSLF solution to embed the file but it is not working for Office 2016. So I am looking some solution to embed and excel file to PPTX slide using XSLF.

Can we use HSLF to create/modify PPTX presentations?

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987387/how-to-insert-an-object-excel-file-into-powerpoint-using-apache-poi

Comment: Thanks @Abra it works for me, the only difficulty is: it is generated PPTX is embed excel file inside PPT only. Is there any way to open embed file as standalone excel like we do manual embedded files ?